# Two slashes in url with optional parameters in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I want to create Users`s shop in my application.
Default urls are:

```
site.com/cars
site.com/parts
```

If user create own shop urls viewed like this:

```
site.com/user_name/cars
site.com/user_name/parts
```

And if user do not create store, parameter `{user_name}` is empty and urls viewed like:

```
site.com//cars
site.com//parts
```

How can I create routes or middlewares for this?

Thank you.

UPD:

My routes

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'site.com'], function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'maintenance_mode']], function()
    {
        Route::group(['prefix' => '{store_name?}', 'namespace' => 'UserOnlineShop', 'middleware' => ['online_shop_tarif']], function(){
            Route::get('/', ['as' => 'user_store.home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
            Route::get('parts/', ['as' => 'parts.index', 'uses' => 'PartsViewController@all_parts']);
            Route::get('catalog/cars_for_parts', ['as' => 'catalog.auto_brands', 'uses' => 'AutoCatalogController@auto_brands']);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest you create separate routes for routes with a user_name and without. Can you show us how your routes are defined?

Comment: you should go for seperate controllers.

Comment: Provide route creator code

Comment: @nozzleman I don't think separate controllers are needed, especially if they're handling the data in the same way and only the way the routes are shown change.

Comment: @michaeltintiuc you may be right, however, OP should post more details for this to become obvious. I was referring to the route-structure which i would realize using a resource controller for each, *cars* and *parts* and nested resource controlles for the nested routes.

Comment: @nozzleman agreed, routes should be separated

Comment: Having the same problem, and still getting two slashes - even though in the controller I assign `null` by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for is this:

```
Route::get('site.com/{user_name?}/cars', function ($user_name = null){

       return view
});
```

The `?` makes the `user_name` oprional and the `null` is needed and can be any other default value.

For what your asking (using named controllers) you may do it this way. Add this to your *route group*:

```
Route::get('site.com/{user_name?}/cars', ['as' => 'site.cars', 'uses' => 'CarController@car_names']);
```

Then in controller do:

```
public function car_names($user_name = null){

    return view;
}
```

Source: [laravel optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

Comment: I specify route names for controller actions (see UPD section in my first message). I think you solution don`t work for me